# Gmail valid email address

Tags: email, gmail, amazon-ses, email-address

I came across a very strange feature of Gmail, I am not 100% sure whether it is a feature or not.

The below email address are valid for a given email address `devank007@gmail.com`:

1. `devank.007@gmail.com`
2. `devank0.07@gmail.com`

How many such cases are there where any email provider accepts these?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is only Gmail that exhibits this behaviour. I've never seen it elsewhere

Comment: This help? https://support.google.com/mail/answer/10313?hl=en

Comment: It would be better if you also add [tag:amazon-ses] tag and add a little note of your issue of sending email to `user@gmil.com` and `user@gmailc.om` in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Google doesn't treat the `.` as a character in their email addresses. Hence `hikingfan@gmail.com`, `hiking.fan@gmail.com` or `hi.kin.g.fan@gmail.com` refer to the same email address.

And somewhat similar is true with using `+` in your Gmail addresses, for example, `hikingfan+banks@gmail.com`, `hikingfan+coding@gmail.com` or `hikingfan@gmail.com` refer to the same email address.

These features of Gmail might help you easily create various filters. Note that the same might not be true for other email service providers.

Source: [googleblog](https://gmail.googleblog.com/2008/03/2-hidden-ways-to-get-more-from-your.html)

Comment: What about devank007@gmailc.om

Comment: Gmail ignores the `.` character only in the username (i.e. before the `@`). `devank007@gmailc.om` is not the same address as `devank007@gmail.com`

Comment: I faced a very strange issue today 

devank007.gmali.com is receiving mails

Comment: As well gmil.com also

Comment: My point here is the above mention gmail spelling are receiving emails.

Comment: I just tested sending email to `my_username@gmil.com` and  `my_username@gmailc.om` and they were bounced (undelivered). How are you sending the emails?

Comment: I think SES is sending them, can't be sure

Comment: If it is so, then your question belongs to tag [tag:amazon-ses], you could research your issue and edit the question appropriately or ask a new question.